# Allow users to ssh to specific user through ldap and stored public keys

Tags: ssh, ldap, git

I recently setup gitolite, where users access git repository with "gitolite" user through ssh.

Now I would like to integrate that into LDAP. Each user has pubkey in LDAP and if he has "git" objectClass, he would be able to access "gitolite" user through ssh.

I know it's possible to store public keys in LDAP, I'm not sure if it possible to allow authentication in "gitosis" account based on objectClass.

**EDIT:** To clarify, with objectClass git, user "foobar" would be able to login as "gitolite" through ssh

Answer (score 1):

The author of *gitolite* has added some features that help support external key stores and group membership information. Search the [CHANGELOG](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/CHANGELOG) for LDAP.

To use an external key store your *sshd* needs to support the usual `.ssh/authorized_keys` file ([this is the file that tells *sshd* to run *gl-auth-command* when a *gitolite* user logs in](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/gitolite-and-ssh.mkd#_how_does_gitolite_use_all_this_ssh_magic_)).

1. Turn off the normal authkey generation (the one based on the `keydir` in the `gitolite-admin` repository):
   `$GL_NO_SETUP_AUTHKEYS = 0;` in your `.gitolite.rc`.
2. Periodically (any time a key is changed, a user is added, etc.):

   1. Extract all the SSH keys from your key store into some convenient, temporary directory (use the same names for key files as if they were in the normal repository-based `keydir`).
   2. Run *gl-setup-authkeys* to have *gitolite* rebuild its part of the `authorized_keys` file.

See [the commit message that introduced *gl-setup-authkeys*](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/commit/c8879264e69f859b9143f53a5db39fb79a2c8d9b) for the author’s own description.

Using externally defined user groups is a bit trickier since it usually involves interposing another program between *sshd* and *gl-auth-command* (the group memberships are passed as extra arguments to *gl-auth-command*). See [“usergroups and LDAP/similar tools”](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/big-config.mkd#_extra_coolness_usergroups_and_LDAP_similar_tools).

Comment: I was thinking of using patched SSH that looks into LDAP for ssh pub key. http://code.google.com/p/openssh-lpk/wiki/Main

Comment: The only part of mystery to be solved is how to hook LDAP to update "gitolite" user on any ssh pub key modification. There seems to be overlays and other not-so-welcome method in OpenLDAP to provide triggers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to try something a little off the wall, you make .ssh/authorized_keys2 be a named pipe and write a script/program that queries LDAP, performs the proper filtering, and then spits out the contents of an authorized_keys keys.  I suggest authorized_keys2 since you're probably using authorized_keys already.

You'd have to be careful with the script (watch for blocking writes, know when to do a fresh query, etc.) but it would give you the right answer every time if you did it right.